# (Jasmine)How can i generate and flush a mock error with error code 406 and contains error.error.error as well?

Tags: angular, http, jasmine

I am working with an angular application and I am unit testing the application with Jasmine.

What I am doing is testing for HTTP request which should return an error code(status) of 406. I am able to do that but extra I need is upon flushing the error it should also include `error.error.error` parameter so that I can apply `forEach` on it.

code to be tested is something like this:

```
get() {
  this.httpClient.get(this.url);
}

getSomething() {
  this.get().subscribe(res => {
    // something
  },(error) => {
    if(error.status == 406) {
      error.error.error.forEach(element => {
        this.showToastMsg("Error", element, "error");
    }
    else {
      // do something else
    }
  });
}
```

how can I generate the error with `error.error.error` way.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests)?

Comment: @dmcgrandle ,thanks for that. But how do i mock `error.error.error` with so that I can cover the code inside `forEach`.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta any update on this ,i am also facing the same issue